# How is $f(\cos x) = \max \{\sin x , -\sin x\}$?

Tags: functions

The given function is $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

I know that the given fuction is equal to $\lvert\cos x\rvert$ but how is it equal to $\max\{\sin x,-\sin x\}$?

A good explanation  will be appreciated.

Comment: $f(\cos x) = |\sin x|$, not $|\cos x|$ (for real $x$).

Comment: It is equal to $|\sin(x)|$, not $|\cos(x)|$. However, $|a|=\max\{a,-a\}$.

Comment: Yes sorry. |sin x| Wrote it by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$
f(\cos x)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\color{red}{\sqrt{\sin^2x}}=\lvert\sin x\rvert
$$
Now, $|a|=\max\{a,-a\}$ for every real $a$.